# Wordpress plugin to authenticate on LDAP or NTLM and handle roles

Tags: php, authentication, wordpress, openldap

In my company we have some technology restrictions. Currently I have a IIS server with PHP. IIS is configured to authenticate users over our Active Directory using NTLM.

I have installed WordPress on this server and am able to login on it using admin user (id=1), and any user is able to read articles and post comments anonymously.

"Thanks" to NTLM, I can retrieve users' login with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']`. This way I can identify (in a plugin) users. But WP doesn't automatically logs them and identifies them.

What I need now is to control users permissions inside Wordpress. I need to attribute roles to them, define groups of people allowed to publish, post and edit without being allowed to publish, comment and register their login on their comments, and also users that are allowed only to read articles (guests) and users not allowed to read articles. Maybe I'll also need to attribute read access relating roles to categories, so that a given role is allowed to read articles from a category and not from another category.

Users are related to departments and have one charge (job title). Users are frequently moving over departments and changing charge. I need to use both to define some roles. I can develop a plugin to hook on some WP filter, retrieve their data and dynamically set their role.

To retrieve their department, charge and name, I could use LDAP. If not possible, I have a MSSQL database that also has their data. So, if I can't use LDAP, I'd need to make WordPress connect to MSSQL and query it.

It's unpractical to register tens of thousands of users in WordPress, and even more to request them to keep their passwords. I need WordPress to identify users and automatically add new ones to its wp_users table. I also need to be able to manually register a few users without requiring them to first enter the site. I then can manually manage users to WordPress roles.

I see 3 possible solutions here:

1) Use IIS's NTLM to authenticate users, and use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` to retrieve their login and log them into WordPress. If they aren't yet registered on wp_users, that's done so. I then query MSSQL for their data. This seems to be the easiest solution.

2) Use IIS's NTLM to authenticate users, and use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` to retrieve their login. Then retrieve their names from AD using LDAP, and provide these data to authenticate WordPress and handle wp_users. This is the most desired solution, but also the most complex.

3) Ignore NTLM and require users to manually provide their login and password to WordPress's login form, then authenticate them over LDAP and handle wp_users. Provided password is their AD one. HTTPS is already working and being forced inside backend. This is the least desired solution, because users are already used to be authenticated from NTLM and may not want or understand the login form (yes...).

Has anybody done that and could help me? Is there a plugin that solves this need, or some open source code I can use as basis to develop a plugin?